# RecyclerView Adapter in CardView display issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have made a RecyclerView Adapter inflated in a CardView as shown in the images below. The cards have hidden layouts which become visible after being clicked on.

[image]

[image]

I am having a problem that when I have many sets of data as cards, and expand one or more cards, some of the cards become abnormal and invisible indefinitely. The cards not in current screen appear to face this problem.

[image]\

[image]

When I scroll through the cards the view becomes more complicated and some cards become smaller and leave white spaces between them while content being of same size.

Please anyone help me solve the problem..

EDIT: This is my layout file:

open_up_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/openUpCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_16x"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_16x"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_8x">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/openUpRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/openUpAuthorImageProgress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/openUpAuthorImage"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_48x"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_48x"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"

                            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/openUpAuthorName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                            android:text="loading.."
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/openUpDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/openUpAuthorName"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12x" />
                    </RelativeLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/openUpTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/openUpImageProgress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpImageView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark" />


                </RelativeLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"></View>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/openUpLikeIcon"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_32x"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_24x"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/thumb_off"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/scale"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpLikeTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"

                        android:text="loading.."
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpCommentIcon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/comment_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpCommentTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"

                        android:text="loading.."
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openUpDeleteText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Delete"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/commentSeparatorView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.5dp"

                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"></View>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/commentSeparatorText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8x"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Comments"
                    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/commentsLL"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/commentsRecyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="Add a comment..">

                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                android:id="@+id/commentEditText"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                            android:id="@+id/commentPostButton"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                            android:text="POST"
                            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.

Comment: you have to undo the layout changes you made later in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: Couldn't I make any changes to the layout at onBindViewHolder? Because I am settting an onClickListener on that small comment icon to make the comments layout visible..